# How do I reduce the boxlength in Lyx?

Tags: lyx, margins, boxes

The box is crossing the margin. How can I reduce the boxlength to the width that I wish. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Thanks ebo. I have got my problem solved. I'm working with lyx hence I think it doesn't make any sense by exporting to latex and adding the document. But in case I find any problem while working on latex I will definitely follow your advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert > Box > Simple Frame inserts a box that spans the entire column/text width. To change this, right-click on the `Box (Minipage, simple frame)` marker and select Settings... There you can adjust the width to suit your needs:

[image]